# recording a video using @capacitor/camera plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, angular14

How to record a video from camera plugin in ionic angular project using capacitor plugins as I'm unable to use cordova plugins in capacitor project

the function will record a video using capacitor/camera plugin and capture it with awesome-cordova-plugins/media-capture and play it with awesome-cordova-plugins/streaming-media plugin.
But as of now capacitor/camera does not support recording and since my application is a capacitor project, cordova plugins cannot be installed.

how to work on this funcyion so it runs on android, web and ios?

Comment: Cordova plugins CAN be installed on capacitor projects!